# zip files in PHP from another directory without a path structure

Tags: php, zip, relative-path

I'm trying to zip two files in another directory without zipping the folder hierarchy as well.

The event is triggered by a button press, which causes Javascript to send information using AJAX to PHP. PHP calls a Perl script (to take advantage of Perl's XLSX writer module and the fact that PHP kind of sucks, but I digress...), which puts the files a few folders down the hierarchy. The relevant code is shown below.

```
system("createFiles.pl -ids ${rows} -test ${test} -path ${path}",$retVal);

`zip ${path}/{$test}_both.zip ${path}/${test}.csv ${path}/${test}.xlsx`;
`zip ${path}/{$test}_csv.zip  ${path}/${test}.csv`;
```

The problem is the zip file has `${path}` hierarchy that has to be navigated before the files are shown as seen below:

### [image: Zip with hierarchy]

I tried doing this (cd before each zip command):

```
system("createFiles.pl -ids ${rows} -test ${test} -path ${path}",$retVal);

`cd ${path}; zip {$test}_both.zip ${test}.csv ${test}.xlsx`;
`cd ${path}; zip {$test}_csv.zip  ${test}.csv`;
```

And it worked, but it seems like a hack. Is there a better way?

Comment: Have you seen the [zip extension](http://php.net/book.zip), built by default since 5.2ish?

Comment: I hadn't seen that before the replies to this thread made me aware, but the build of PHP on my work system was apparently built without ZipArchive. In phpinfo(), it's explicitly excluded. I have no idea why, but it looks like I'm SOL if I want to do this internal to my PHP script.

Comment: If you're using OS-provided PHP builds, then you're going to see basically `--without-everything`, as that's how they like doing dynamic extensions.  Scroll down the big list-o-extensions until the Zs, it may well be present after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ZipArchive answer by Oldskool is good. I've used ZipArchive and it works. However, I recommend [PclZip](http://www.phpconcept.net/pclzip/) instead as it is more versatile (e.g. allows for zipping with no compression, ideal if you are zipping up images which are already compressed, much faster). PclZip supports the [PCLZIP_OPT_REMOVE_ALL_PATH](http://www.phpconcept.net/pclzip/user-guide/30) option to remove all file paths. e.g.

```
$zip = new PclZip("$path/{$test}_both.zip");
$files = array("$path/$test.csv", "$path/$test.xlsx");

// create the Zip archive, without paths or compression (images are already compressed)
$properties = $zip->create($files, PCLZIP_OPT_REMOVE_ALL_PATH);
if (!is_array($properties)) {
    die($zip->errorInfo(true));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternate solution and the explanation of the PclZip class. I can't use either class (ZipArchive or PclZip) because of dependency issues on my work systems, but I tried both solutions at home with success.

Comment: Bummer! Note that your system only needs [zlib](http://php.net/manual/en/book.zlib.php) support for PclZip, it doesn't need ZipArchive. But if it ain't compiled in, it won't work :(

Answer (score 1):

If you use PHP 5 >= 5.2.0 you can use the [ZipArchive](http://php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php) class. You can then use the full path as source filename and just the filename as target name. Like this:

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;
if($zip->open("{$test}_both.zip", ZIPARCHIVE::OVERWRITE) === true) {
    // Add the files here with full path as source, short name as target
    $zip->addFile("${path}/${test}.csv", "${test}.csv");
    $zip->addFile("${path}/${test}.xlsx", "${test}.xlsx");
    $zip->close();
} else {
    die("Zip creation failed.");
}

// Same for the second archive
$zip2 = new ZipArchive;
if($zip2->open("{$test}_csv.zip", ZIPARCHIVE::OVERWRITE) === true) {
    // Add the file here with full path as source, short name as target
    $zip2->addFile("${path}/${test}.csv", "${test}.csv");
    $zip2->close();
} else {
    die("Zip creation failed.");
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the code snippet and the information. I really appreciate it!